# Html insert json value to an element and convert this to an object

Tags: javascript, html, json

I want to put value on element that is JSON value, but when i read this value i want to parse the json and make the value an object if this is a JSON format, if not return the string, this is what i am trying to do but it is not working.

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li value="{name:34}">Item Two</li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
function getValue() {
    var ele =  document.querySelector('ul'),
    value = ele.firstElementChild.getAttribute('value');
    try {
      value = JSON.parse(value);
    } catch (e) {
      alert('invalid json');
    }
    return value;
}
```

so for example if the value is in JSON format i want the function to return the value as an object that i could write value.name and get 34 in this case, but if the value is simple string like "itemOne" so i expect the function to return the string "itemOne".

Comment: What do you mean, make the value an object?

Comment: make him js object like this:  JSON.parse(value).name

Comment: So, now your code isn't working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Valid JSON string should be properly quoted. In your case key "name" is missing double quotes. Correct attribute would look like `value='{"name": 34}'`.

Another recommendation. While you can use `value` (and any other) attribute, it's not very semantically right since `LI` element doesn't have `value` attributes and properties. It's better to go with `data-value` attribute which will pass W3C validation:

```js
function getValue() {
    var ele = document.querySelector('ul'),
        value = ele.firstElementChild.getAttribute('data-value');
    try {
        value = JSON.parse(value);
    } catch (e) {
        alert('invalid json');
    }
    return value;
}

document.write(JSON.stringify( getValue() , null, 4));
```

```html
<ul>
    <li data-value='{"name":34}'>Item Two</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your html code, more specifically, property value of li is not a valid JSON.

Replace this:

```
<ul>
    <li value="{name:34}">Item Two</li>
  </ul>
```

With this:

```
<ul>
        <li value='{"name" :34}'>Item Two</li>
      </ul>
```

**Valid json format is a string quoted.**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function tryParse (jsonString){
    try {
        var obj = JSON.parse(jsonString);

        if (obj  && typeof obj  === "object" && obj  !== null) {
            return obj ;
        }
    }
    catch (e) { 
           return jsonString;
    }

    return jsonString;
};
```

And your function will be like this:

```
function getValue() {
    var ele =  document.querySelector('ul'),
    value = ele.firstElementChild.getAttribute('value');
    tryParse(value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Check that the JSON is valid.**

Using [This Validator](http://jsonlint.com/) we can see that the JSON text is missing double quotes around "name".

Make sure to use HTML entities when using double quotes in HTML attributes.

See below code:

```js
getValue();

function getValue() {
  var ele = document.querySelector('ul'),
    value = ele.firstElementChild.getAttribute('value');
  try {
    value = JSON.parse(value);
  } catch (e) {
    alert('invalid json');
  }
  return value;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li value="{&quot;name&quot;:34}">Item Two</li>
</ul>
```